# WinForm button keeps focus

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, c#-2.0

I have a winform with several buttons, when I hit a button, it runs the Click Event Handler, and then the button keeps selected, so if then I hit the ENTER key in the keyboard, it will run the Click event handler for that button again.

I guess this is the default behavior for a button (keeping it selected when its clicked) but I cant find a way to remove that behavior.

I tried the methods `Focus()` and `Select()` for another control, but the button is still Selected/Focused/Active

any help?

Comment: There is a reason you can’t disable this behaviour. It is *standard* and users *expect* it. If you remove this and/or disable the Enter key, your users will hate you and think you’re incompetent. If you think you *need* to remove this and/or disable Enter, *you have a serious flaw in your UI design.* Rethink your design before it is too late. Don’t mess with expected standard UI behaviour.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because MY CLIENT is requesting THIS behaivior. I put it clear: this is the default behaivior but I was wondering if it was possible to change!, thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don´t want a user to hit enter and fire the event again while it is still running you can disable the button while running the handler code (with a finally in case something messes up)

Edit:

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnOk.Enable = false;
    try
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        btnOk.Enable = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant disable the button, because the users should be able to click it with the button. I also cant disable the ENTER key (it's used for another things)

Comment: I mean disable it on the handled event... that should be the first thing you should do and then enable it backa again of course